# PostBack DataBind error: "Ensure that the control is added to the page before calling DataBind."

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback, sqldatasource, data-binding

I have a program that allows the user to use a few dropdowns to pick a topic and attribute, then the data are pulled that match on both of those conditions.  In the gridview are a lot of templatefields use textboxes for instant editing (a submit button saves all changes) as well as a template with a dropdown bound to a parameter.  This was all working hunky-dory for quite a while.

Then, we changed some of the data in the tables (keeping all the same field names) and now the page loads perfectly fine on launch but then as soon as you select something different in any of the drilldown dropdowns the page fails.  I get an error saying

> "The DropDownList control 'TagDDL' does not have a naming container. 
>   Ensure that the control is added to the page before calling DataBind."

(TagDDL is the dropdown in the templatefield in gridview).  If I simply remove this templatefield, I get a similar (though different) error on a hyperlinkfield, removing this gives me an error in a boundfield, so obviously it's not tied to any one thing.

My idea is that it has something to do with how databinding works on post-back, since the page loads perfectly initially, the dropdowns have 'Enable PostBack' and the error messages refer to DataBind.  Any ideas?

The SqlDataSource that builds Gridview (leaving out the drilldown dropdowns for now)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MasterTable" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:spvConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="exec pmtv2.maintable_display 1, @IPG_Assigned, @CompetitorName, @enterprise_zone, @Banner, @BrandName"
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChooseBanner" Name="Banner" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChooseIPGs" Name="IPG_Assigned" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChooseBrands" Name="BrandName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChooseComps" Name="CompetitorName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChooseZone" Name="enterprise_zone" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

```
 <div id="MasterDiv" style="width:90%">
        <asp:GridView ID="MasterDisplay" runat="server"
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="productKey,banner,enterprise_zone,userID" DataSourceID="MasterTable" 
            OnRowDataBound="MasterDisplay_RowDataBound"
            OnSorting="MasterDisplay_Sorting"
            class="mGrid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="mGridAlt">
```

```
 </AlternatingRowStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="productdescriptionlong">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                           <a href="javascript:openPopup('JustinPractice4.aspx?UPC=<%#  Eval("UPC") %>    
&banner=<%# Eval("banner") %>&enterprise_zone=<%# Eval("enterprise_zone") %>')"><%# Eval("productdescriptionlong")%></a>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BrandName" HeaderText="Brand" 
                    SortExpression="BrandName" />
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Price" SortExpression="new_base_retail">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="RWNextPrice" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("new_base_retail", "{0:N2}") %>' Width="60px"
                            class="calculate" onchange="lineItemRipple(this)"
                            Visible='<%# ShowBox %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="RNextPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("new_base_retail", "{0:c}") %>'
                            Visible='<%# ShowLabel %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="lineCode" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("line_code") %>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:ImageField DataImageURLField="unique_flags" HeaderText="Flags" 
                    DataImageURLFormatString="Media/Images/{0}.png" SortExpression="unique_flags"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tag Type" SortExpression="tag_type">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="TagDDL" runat="server"
                            DataSourceID="dimTags"
                            DataTextField="Tag_type_name"
                            DataValueField="Tag_type_name"
                            SelectedValue='<%#Bind("tag_type") %>'
                            visible='<%#ShowBox %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:Label ID="TagR" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# Eval("tag_type") %>'
                            Visible='<%# ShowLabel %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
 <asp:Button ID="Commit" runat="server" Text="Commit Changes" OnClick="Commit_Click"
            class="button"/>
```

and the relevant code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ErrorMsg.Text = "test45"; 
    }

protected void MasterDisplay_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
        DataSourceSelectArguments sr = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
        DataView dv = (DataView)CheckForCommit.Select(sr);
        if (dv.Count != 0) {
            CommittedOrNot.Text = dv[0][0].ToString();
        }
//pulling results from a SqlDataSource confirming presence of data

       //calculations to maintain a running tally of certain fields for later use
    }

protected void Commit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string tagValue = "FLAG";
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in MasterDisplay.Rows) {
            tagValue = ((DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("TagDDL")).SelectedValue;
            MasterDisplay.UpdateRow(gvr.RowIndex, false);
        } //for every row, update it
        MasterDisplay.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: It's definitely got to be PostBack/DataBind related. Putting if(!Page.IsPostBack) MasterDisplay.DataBind(); in the Page_Load causes a crash immediately upon running.

Comment: Have you put breakpoints in your code?

Comment: It was a simple error of trying to add to a DDL before I had actually pulled the data needed to bind it.  Changing the order of things slightly did the trick.

Comment: you can post that as answer and choose it select answer so other can find it useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple error of trying to add to a DDL before I had actually pulled the data needed to bind it. Changing the order of things slightly did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you found your answer.  I had a similar issue on a UserControl (ascx) that was being loaded a run-time.  I, too, had made a change to my data source and the corresponding sql data sources.  (In my case, I was replacing the sql data sources with an entity model.)

What I found was that one of my controls would bind to the new data source (via the code behind) with no problems.  The code looked as follows:

```
gridSomeData.DataSource = controller.GetListOfAssociatedParts();
gridSomeData.DataBind();
```

However, in the same method, the next section of code would fail when the DataBind() method was called.  The code looked as follows:

```
drpDataList.DataSource = controller.GetListOfParts();
drpDataList.DataTextField = "PartID"
drpDataList.DataValueField = "PartKey"
drpDataList.DataBind();
```

It turned out, that when I removed the prior ASCX markup for the SqlDataSource objects, I failed to remove the reference in the DataSourceID attribute of the drop down control.  So when I called the DataBind() method, the binding engine checked the attributes of the control, found a name DataSourceID, and immediately went looking for it in the control hierarchy of the UserControl.  When the binding engine failed to find the object, it threw the exception "The DropDownList control [...] does not have a naming container..."

I will admit that this particular exception is somewhat misleading, as it is really the binder being confused over which instructions to follow for the data source (the code behind, or the markup in the ascx file).

I hope this helps with some perspective. :)